# Unable to define quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy in quarkus version 2.14.1.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, hibernate-mapping, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I am trying to map hibernate properties to the database and I do not want to add @Column for  entities having camel case

```
@Entity
public class User extends PanacheEntity{
  @Column(name = "user_name")
  String userName;
}
```

I am trying to set the below property but it does not work for quarkus version 2.14.1.Final (not sure about other versions)

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.physical-naming-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After debugging the code, I found that `HibernateOrmRuntimeConfigPersistenceUnit` class has a property `unsupportedProperties` to use for properties that cannot be defined explicitly and it works if the property is defined as.

`quarkus.hibernate-orm.unsupported-properties."hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`

But I think the property should have been provided explicitly. Quarkus team could let know if it can introduce it since `Entity` mapping has these kind of requirement very often.